# How to add ethernet settings to android with xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ethernet

Recently, I had to connect my mobile to the internet by using a USB cable since neither WiFi or cellular data are possible in my case. So the only solution left is to use Ethernet and a USB-to-Ethernet adapter, but `android 8`, `android 8.1` does not have Ethernet settings because the default IP acquisition method is dynamic allocation (`DHCP`), but in my case I need to manually set a `static IP`.

So after some research I've found this article : https://www.programmersought.com/article/91373846940/

and this Git:
https://github.com/Dufre/Android-Settings-Ethernet/blob/master/0001-Ethernet-Add-Static-IP-Settiings.patch

The problem is that I couldn't figure out how to proceed.

If anyone could provide some assistance, it would be tremendous!

Comment: What you link to is an article that patches the Settings App in the Android OS. Is this something you can do?

Comment: First of all, i believe that you should rephrase the question because DHCP is a protocol of obtaining a vacant IP Address. What that means is that once you plug and play your phone with the ethernet cable it should act as a client and obtain an IP address from the DHCP Server or Router(if it is configured to give out IP's).
Second of all, if by any means, when you plug the ethernet cable to your phone you dont get an dynamically allocated IP address, that has nothing to do with the DHCP server settings.

Comment: @Cheesebaron no not really, I guess I will need some serious help on how to do it, or another solution maybe ?

Comment: Setup your DHCP server to serve the same IP address to this device if it needs the same IP everytime?

Comment: Yes you could preconfigure the DHCP server to lease the same IP to you android phone.
Have you checked this ? -> https://www.wirelesshack.org/how-to-connect-a-android-to-wired-ethernet-connection.html
The article saies that any higher version of android is basically plug an play. Also, "While most will not have any issues the phone or tablet must have the drivers for the chipset in the Ethernet adapter to work."